# How to modify list of list elements python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists

```
 check = [['KH8X070.jpeg', 'ZDO9A8O.jpeg', 'ZW25RD8.jpeg', '6ZLXW92.jpeg', 'HVLA5UT.jpeg', 'A4UDC12.jpeg', '2X5KO9A.jpeg', '5HZR4VV.jpeg', '24FWS4S.jpeg'], ['Z2QC6PW.jpeg', 'EHMK14E.jpeg', 'RTV0PRH.jpeg', '71S643D.jpeg', 'KECHDQ9.jpeg', 'RU6PYPB.jpeg'], ['UG9Z4SQ.jpeg', 'H0Y3SYV.jpeg', '61HCFOK.jpeg', '14KE527.jpeg', 'XMSM050.jpeg', '5KFI2V3.jpeg', 'QSJMKUB.jpeg', 'S6TX0ZM.jpeg', '8JV3K1Y.jpeg', 'XI9OOI7.jpeg', 'JMWDOPM.jpeg'], ['0SAXG3I.jpeg', 'LA5HJNO.jpeg', 'PHHAUSA.jpeg', '900Z7S7.jpeg']]
```

such that I have:

```
 check = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3]]
```

I want to modify it such that in index list 0 of the list of list, I'll have 0's all through, in index 1 I would have 1's all through, in index 2 I'll have 2's all through and so on like that.

```
for i, j in enumerate(check):
  checks = [...]
```

I know it should be a list comprehension there, but don't just know how to go about it. That's why I have come here for help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take with an one-liner code :

```
>>> [map(lambda val : i, arr) for i,arr in enumerate(check)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above won't quite give you the result you need. But what you can do is

```
arr = []
for i, j in enumerate(check):
    length = j
    arr.append([i]*length)
```

This should work perfectly, I tried it out and it worked fine. Let me know how it works for you.